# Why do Window functions fail with "Window function X does not take a frame specification"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use Spark 1.4 [window functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) in pyspark 1.4.1

but getting mostly errors or unexpected results.
Here is a very simple example that I think should work:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

l = [(1,101),(2,202),(3,303),(4,404),(5,505)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l,["a","b"])

wSpec = Window.orderBy(df.a).rowsBetween(-1,1)

df.select(df.a, func.rank().over(wSpec).alias("rank"))  
    ==> Failure org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function rank does not take a frame specification.

df.select(df.a, func.lag(df.b,1).over(wSpec).alias("prev"), df.b, func.lead(df.b,1).over(wSpec).alias("next"))  
    ===>  org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function lag does not take a frame specification.;


wSpec = Window.orderBy(df.a)

df.select(df.a, func.rank().over(wSpec).alias("rank"))
    ===> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentTypeException: One or more arguments are expected.

df.select(df.a, func.lag(df.b,1).over(wSpec).alias("prev"), df.b, func.lead(df.b,1).over(wSpec).alias("next")).collect()

    [Row(a=1, prev=None, b=101, next=None), Row(a=2, prev=None, b=202, next=None), Row(a=3, prev=None, b=303, next=None)]
```

As you can see, if I add `rowsBetween` frame specification, neither `rank()` nor `lag/lead()` window functions recognize it: "Window function does not take a frame specification".

If I omit the `rowsBetween` frame specification at leas `lag/lead()` do not throw exceptions but return unexpected (for me) result: always `None`. And the `rank()` still doesn't work with different exception.

Can anybody help me to get my window functions right?

**UPDATE**

All right, that starts to look as a pyspark bug.
I have prepared the same test in pure Spark (Scala, spark-shell):

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val l: List[Tuple2[Int,Int]] = List((1,101),(2,202),(3,303),(4,404),(5,505))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(l).map(i => Row(i._1,i._2))
val schemaString = "a b"
val schema = StructType(schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, IntegerType, true)))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val wSpec = Window.orderBy("a").rowsBetween(-1,1)
df.select(df("a"), rank().over(wSpec).alias("rank"))
    ==> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function rank does not take a frame specification.;

df.select(df("a"), lag(df("b"),1).over(wSpec).alias("prev"), df("b"), lead(df("b"),1).over(wSpec).alias("next"))
    ===> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Window function lag does not take a frame specification.;


val wSpec = Window.orderBy("a")
df.select(df("a"), rank().over(wSpec).alias("rank")).collect()
    ====> res10: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4], [5,5])

df.select(df("a"), lag(df("b"),1).over(wSpec).alias("prev"), df("b"), lead(df("b"),1).over(wSpec).alias("next"))
    ====> res12: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1,null,101,202], [2,101,202,303], [3,202,303,404], [4,303,404,505], [5,404,505,null])
```

Even though the `rowsBetween` cannot be applied in Scala, both `rank()` and `lag()/lead()` work as I expect when `rowsBetween` is omitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell there two different problems. Window frame definition is simply not supported by Hive [`GenericUDAFRank`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ac755ebe26361a4647d53db2a28500f71697b276/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFRank.java#L45), [`GenericUDAFLag`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ac755ebe26361a4647d53db2a28500f71697b276/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFLag.java#L41) and [`GenericUDAFLead`](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ac755ebe26361a4647d53db2a28500f71697b276/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDAFLead.java#L37) so errors you see are an expected behavior.

Regarding issue with the following PySpark code

```
wSpec = Window.orderBy(df.a)
df.select(df.a, func.rank().over(wSpec).alias("rank"))
```

it looks like it is related to my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/31948194/1560062 and should be addressed by [SPARK-9978](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9978). As far now you can make it work by changing window definition to this:

```
wSpec = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(df.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark,the following Window spec will throw error.

```
joined_windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("a_x").orderBy('justDate', 'table_name').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
```

Error thrown :

```
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: Cannot specify window frame for lag function.
```

While if we omit rowBetween specification, it doesn't throw error.

```
joined_windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("a_x").orderBy('justDate', 'table_name')  ## NO ERROR
```